# what is alternative of EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

-----MYSQL CODE-----

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uativiza_v3`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Procedure name`(IN p_processno INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN
    CALL offline_logger (p_processno,'Exception caught -----Exception caught : RollingBack!') ;
    ROLLBACK ;
  END ;
  START TRANSACTION ;
        Insert into table1 select * from table2
 COMMIT ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

--Summary 
When any Exception occured at time of insertion then above procedure call offline_logger procedure

Above code i have to migrate into postgresql. So how to handle the Handler(Exception) in postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is alternative of (DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION) in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641336/what-is-alternative-of-declare-exit-handler-for-sqlexception-in-postgresql)

Comment: Please describe what this is supposed to do.

Comment: how to handle  EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION in postgresql

Comment: I want to convert above code into postgresql .but postgresql doesnot support Handler

Comment: You want an exception handler: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would roughly translate to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name(IN p_processno integer)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table1
      SELECT * FROM table2;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      CALL offline_logger(
              p_processno,
              'Exception caught -----Exception caught : RollingBack!'
           );
END;$$;
```

The `INSERT` is rolled back automatically when an exception occurs.